# cadwork plugin dosent load on client workstation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

the application cadwork dosent load my plugin, on client workstation.
on Developer Workstation its work fine.
is there any log files or something else how locate what happens, why
cadwork cant load it.

thx for help